# Angular 9 - transform Response

Tags: rxjs, angular9

Trying to learn how to transform http responses using pipes. The following function is called outside of that service:

```
public requestProjectList(assetId: number) {
    this.service.get(url)
    .pipe(map(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }));
  }
```

However I am not getting data.What am I doing wrong? Please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unlike promises, observables are "cold" until they're subscribed to, meaning the function and the transforms won't run until you subscribe.

```
public requestProjectList(assetId: number) {
    // return the observable
    return this.service.get(url)
    .pipe(map(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return data; // also return inside map prefer `tap` for simple logging
    }));
}
```

then call your function and subscribe to trigger:

```
this.service.requestProjectList(id).subscribe(result => console.log(result, "got it"))
```

Comment: What type do I need to return from requestProjectList function?

Comment: `Observable<ReturnTypeOfData>`

Comment: If I use Observable<any[IProjectList]> I get interface IProjectList
Type 'IProjectList' cannot be used as an index type.. I am returning return this.projectList; where projectList is defined like public projectList: Array<IProjectList> = [null];